# Apache2 replace substring in RewriteRule capture?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I was wondering - is it possible to replace (all instances) of a substring inside a RewriteRule capture?

Here is an example, that I've started testing in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ :

For original/input url: `https://example.com/subfold/dl/testDir/subTestDir/test.png`

I have the rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfold/dl/
RewriteRule ^subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$ httpdocs__$1__$2 [NC,L]
```

... and I get output URL: `https://example.com/httpdocs__testDir/subTestDir__test.png`

So, essentially, I capture the entire subpath after `^subfold/dl` into `$1` variable, and the filename into `$2`; so in this case: `$1` = `testDir/subTestDir`, and `$2` = `test.png`.

So what I want, is to replace all instances of `/` (forward slash) in `$1` with `%2F`, before it gets applied to the output URL -> so that I would eventually get output URL: `https://example.com/httpdocs__testDir%2FsubTestDir__test.png`

Is there a way to do this with Apache2 RewriteRule's - and if so, how?

---

EDIT: Jeez:

[image]

... at least give me this message the very first time I paste `mysite.com` - now I have to waste extra time reworking my entire example, after I spent all this time to make it work to begin with `:(`... Computers are never going to make life easier, are they? Just more ads, crap and espionage ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, got somewhere (also see somewhat related post [Debugging Apache2 RewriteRule (with headers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614750/debugging-apache2-rewriterule-with-headers))

So, the only thing I could find somewhat working is [Using RewriteMap - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html). Now, since I use a Windows build of Apache, it gets somewhat extra tricky - but is still doable.

There is very skint information online on how to get this working; crucial information was found here [RewriteMap prg: issue on Windows - Apache Web Server forum at WebmasterWorld - By Pubcon](https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3461619.htm):

> RewriteMap program is kicked off IFF the "RewriteEngine On" directive is OUTSIDE  as below

In my case, also, the RewriteMap program starts if and only if the RewriteMap directive is OUTSIDE `<Location>`; AND the "RewriteEngine On" is OUTSIDE `<Location>` - in any other case, the program does not start.

Second thing we should be careful about is this, from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html :

> When a MapType of prg is used, the MapSource is a filesystem path to
> an executable program which will providing the mapping behavior. This
> can be a compiled binary file, or a program in an interpreted language
> such as Perl or Python.
>
> This program is started once, when the Apache HTTP Server is started,
> and then communicates with the rewriting engine via STDIN and STDOUT.
> That is, for each map function lookup, it expects one argument via
> STDIN, and should return one new-line terminated response string on
> STDOUT. If there is no corresponding lookup value, the map program
> should return the four-character string "NULL" to indicate this.
>
> External rewriting programs are not started if they're defined in a
> context that does not have RewriteEngine set to on.

In other words - the program used HAS to open its STDIN and STDOUT - *AND* it **MUST** block continuously; even if what you wanted to do was `perl -i -pe's/SEARCH/REPLACE/'`, that kind of a program reads input, processes, provides output, *and exits* - and so in this case, it would not do us any good.

So, based on the example given in rewritemap.html - here is a Perl script that replaces forward slash (`/`) with `%2F`, while blocking continuously, called `convslash.pl`, saved in `C:\bin\Apache24\bin\`

```perl
#!C:/msys64/usr/bin/perl.exe
$| = 1; # Turn off I/O buffering
while (<STDIN>) {
    s|/|%2F|g; # Replace / with %2F
    print $_;
}
```

Then, I add this in my `httpd.conf`:

```bsh
# the below starts and runs ONLY if RewriteEngine On is outside of <Location>; also a cmd.exe window is started (plus another for perl!)
#RewriteMap doprg "prg:c:/msys64/usr/bin/perl.exe c:/bin/Apache24/bin/dash2under.pl"

# the below is slightly better - only one cmd.exe window is started:
RewriteMap doprg "prg:c:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c start /b c:/msys64/usr/bin/perl.exe c:/bin/Apache24/bin/convslash.pl"

# we MUST have RewriteEngine On here, outside of location - otherwise the RewriteMap program will never start:
RewriteEngine On

<Location /subfold/dl>

Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit 

# first RewriteCond - this is just so we can capture the relevant parts into environment variables:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ONE:%1,E=TWO:%2,NE]

# the above RewriteRule does not rewrite - but passes the input string further;
# so here, let's have another such RewriteRule - just so we can set our processed/desired output to a variable, which we can "print" via headers:
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MODDED:subfold/dl/${doprg:%{ENV:ONE}}/%{ENV:TWO},NE]

# the original URL will finally pass through unmodified to the "file handler" which will attempt to map it to the filesystem, it will fail, and return 404.
# the below headers should be returned along with that 404:

Header always set X-ONE "%{ONE}e"
Header always set X-TWO "%{TWO}e"
Header always set X-INPUT "%{INPUT}e"
Header always set X-MODDED "%{MODDED}e"
Header always set X-REQ "expr=%{REQUEST_URI}"

</Location>
```

So, now I start the server locally (`./bin/httpd.exe`), and to test this, I issue a request with curl:

```
$ curl -IkL http://127.0.0.1/subfold/dl/my/spec/test.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 18 Oct 2021 17:08:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1j
X-ONE: my/spec
X-TWO: test.html
X-INPUT: (null)
X-MODDED: subfold/dl/my%2Fspec/test.html
X-REQ: /subfold/dl/my/spec/test.html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

... and finally, we can see in the X-MODDED header, that indeed we managed to replace only a substring in (what would be) the rewritten URL ...

Well, I wish that this was documented somehow, and I didn't have to waste like 8 hours of my life to figure this out - but who cares, in couple of years there will be new servers du jour, where all of this will be irrelevant, so more time will have to be wasted - all of it to serve more crap, ads and espionage.