# Debugging Apache2 RewriteRule (with headers)?

Tags: debugging, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, http-headers, apache2

So, I've seen [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) - but I have a hard time making use of the suggestions there.

Basically, what I would wish for, is to see what the input and output is of every RewriteCond and RewriteRule entry, as well as the order in which they run, but I cannot seem to find anything that will help me understand that.

So here is a brief example, from what I've read so far: I'm running Apache2 locally on my Windows 10 machine; and I have the following in `httpd.conf`:

```bsh
<Location /subfold/dl>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfold/dl/
RewriteRule ^subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$ httpdocs__$1__$2 [ENV=RSLT:AAA,NE]
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/subfold/dl/" REWRGO=Yes
# "without 'always' your additions will only go out on succesful responses"
Header always set X-REWRGO "%{REWRGO}e"
Header always set X-RSLT "%{RSLT}e"

</Location>
```

So, here I basically create a wrong rewrite rule, which means the server will always respond with 404.

Because of that, I have to use the `always` keyword with Header - otherwise response headers never get sent (see [Apache: difference between "Header always set" and "Header set"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502968/apache-difference-between-header-always-set-and-header-set)).

Eventually, what I'd want, is to capture `[ENV=RSLT:httpdocs__$1__$2,NE]` the output of the rewrite rule in an environment variable, and then write that variable in the response header. Unfortunately, that does not quite work - when I try to issue a request with curl:

```
$ curl -IkL http://127.0.0.1/subfold/dl/my/test.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 18 Oct 2021 10:29:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1j
X-REWRGO: Yes
X-RSLT: (null)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

... we can see that the `REWRGO` variable value *did* end up in the header - but the `RSLT` is seen as having value `null`, even if it was explicitly set to value `AAA`; furthermore, my log settings:

```
LogLevel notice setenvif:trace8 rewrite:trace8
```

... print this in Apache2's `error.log`:

```
[Mon Oct 18 12:29:12.151566 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 11368:tid 1932] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:9848] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#14c6370][rid#7031e10/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /subfold/dl/my/test.html

[Mon Oct 18 12:29:12.152573 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 11368:tid 1932] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:9848] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#14c6370][rid#7031e10/initial] pass through /subfold/dl/my/test.html

[Mon Oct 18 12:29:12.152573 2021] [setenvif:trace2] [pid 11368:tid 1932] mod_setenvif.c(630): [client 127.0.0.1:9848] Setting REWRGO

[Mon Oct 18 12:29:12.152573 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 11368:tid 1932] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:9848] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#14c6370][rid#7031e10/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] add path info postfix: C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold -> C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/my/test.html

[Mon Oct 18 12:29:12.152573 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 11368:tid 1932] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:9848] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#14c6370][rid#7031e10/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] applying pattern '^subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$' to uri 'C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/my/test.html'

[Mon Oct 18 12:29:12.153551 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 11368:tid 1932] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:9848] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#14c6370][rid#7031e10/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] pass through C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold
```

So, I have everything in this log, *except* what I need - and that is: what was the final URL string that came out of the RewriteRule (wrong or not)?

But, regardless - the error log shows me, at least, that the RewriteRule *has* been triggered, and that would make me expect that the `RSLT` environment variable should be set too; but it is *not* - as we can see in the header, it is `null`. So cannot really use this technique for debugging, either.

(I *guess*, this environment variable problem is due to, as noted in [RewriteCond with SetEnv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362746/rewritecond-with-setenv) , which quotes [Setting Environment Variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html#setting):

> The SetEnv directive runs late during request processing meaning that directives
> such as SetEnvIf and RewriteCond will not see the variables set with it.

But then, the same post says setting an environment variable within the RewriteRule *should* work - and yet, in my example, it does *not*?)

Can anyone help me with, how can I correctly capture the output of a RewriteRule, and then print it somehow - for instance, as a header value - for each request URL that I might send through, say, `curl`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, managed to get a bit further with this.

First, let's consider this `httpd.conf` snippet:

```bsh
<Location /subfold/dl>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions AllowAnyURI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfold/dl/
#RewriteRule subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$ httpdocs__$1__$2
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=RSLT:$1,CO=;frontdoor;yes_"$1";127.0.0.1;1440;/,NE,PT,L]
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/subfold/dl/" REWRGO=Yes
# "without 'always' your additions will only go out on succesful responses"
SetEnvIf Cookie "frontdoor=([^;]+)" MyFrontDoor=%1
Header always set X-REWRGO "%{REWRGO}e"
Header always set X-RSLT "%{RSLT}e"
Header always set X-FRONTDOOR "%{MyFrontDoor}e"
Header always set X-Request_URI1 "%{REQUEST_URI}e"
Header always set X-Request_URI2 "expr=%{REQUEST_URI}"

</Location>
```

When I have this in my `httpd.conf`, and I start Apache `httpd.exe`, and I issue a request, this is what I get now:

```
$ curl -IkL http://127.0.0.1/subfold/dl/my/test.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 18 Oct 2021 12:35:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1j
X-REWRGO: Yes
X-RSLT: C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/my/test.html
X-FRONTDOOR: (null)
X-Request_URI1: (null)
X-Request_URI2: /subfold/dl/my/test.html
Set-Cookie: frontdoor=yes_"C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/my/test.html"; path=/; domain=127.0.0.1; expires=Tue, 19-Oct-2021 12:35:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

So, something started working ... and what I gather from this:

First, the `AllowAnyURI` is not really needed here - I thought it was because https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html says:

> When RewriteRule is used in VirtualHost or server context with version 2.2.22 or later of httpd, mod_rewrite will only process the rewrite rules if the request URI is a URL-path.

I was afraid that my request URI might not be recognized, so I enabled `AllowAnyURI` - but that does not seem to be the issue here.

So here is what this tests: with `RewriteRule (.*) -` we basically have a "passthrough" - the original request does not get rewritten; again https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html :

> The Substitution may be a: ... 
> - (dash) 
> A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

... and we also have the corresponding [PT] flag there. Then, since the entire match request is in parentheses `(.*)` and therefore captured, we can output it with `$1` in the same line; and finally, we both set an environment variable RSLT to this, as well as a cookie.

Now here is where I got surprised: what ends up in the "Pattern" part of the rewrite rule is *not* the original URL - it is what Apache would see as the translation of this URL to the *local filesystem*!!!

I first noticed this, when I got split values for the cookie, as it always splits on colons (`:`) - even if it is string data in a variable (which however did contain `C:/..`, which is what end up being split)! Hence I tried to use double quotes, but that did not work - what worked eventually was https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co :

> If a literal ':' character is needed in any of the cookie fields, an alternate syntax is available. To opt-in to the alternate syntax, the cookie "Name" should be preceded with a ';' character, and field separators should be specified as ';'.

In any case, here we've had:

- `http://127.0.0.1` `/subfold/dl/my/test.html` - original request
- `C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs` `/subfold/dl/my/test.html` - what Apache mapped that request to, in the local filesystem

And essentially, this was the problem with the code in the OP: `RewriteRule ^subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$ ...` would mean: replace the string that starts with `subfold...` - however, the string ``C:/bin/...` definitely does not start like that, and so the Rewrite*Rule* never matches, and does not execute!

I guess, another confusion for me was, that `(.*)` as the Pattern (first arg) in RewriteRule, typically looks like the REQUEST_URI - but that is within .htaccess in a directory; https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html again:

> - In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html"). This is the (%-decoded) URL-path.
> - In per-directory context (Directory and .htaccess), the Pattern is matched against *only a partial path*, for example a request of "/app1/index.html" may result in comparison against "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the RewriteRule is defined.

... where

> REQUEST_URI
> The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING

So, my bad was, that I was assuming `(.*)` as Pattern in the RewriteRule would be matched to the path component (REQUEST_URI-like) and I attempted matching versus that; whereas, in this case, it was actually the full filesystem path, starting with `C:/...`!

The being said, we can now uncomment the line `RewriteRule subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$ httpdocs__$1__$2` in the above snippet - realising that this time, the match does not have the starting caret (`^`), which would means "match the start of string":

```bsh
<Location /subfold/dl>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfold/dl/
RewriteRule subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$ httpdocs__$1__$2
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=RSLT:$1,CO=;frontdoor;yes_"$1";127.0.0.1;1440;/,NE,PT,L]
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/subfold/dl/" REWRGO=Yes
# "without 'always' your additions will only go out on succesful responses"
SetEnvIf Cookie "frontdoor=([^;]+)" MyFrontDoor=%1
Header always set X-REWRGO "%{REWRGO}e"
Header always set X-RSLT "%{RSLT}e"
Header always set X-FRONTDOOR "%{MyFrontDoor}e"
Header always set X-Request_URI1 "%{REQUEST_URI}e"
Header always set X-Request_URI2 "expr=%{REQUEST_URI}"

</Location>
```

... and the response to this is:

```
$ curl -IkL http://127.0.0.1/subfold/dl/my/test.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 18 Oct 2021 13:18:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1j
X-REWRGO: Yes
X-RSLT: C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html
X-FRONTDOOR: (null)
X-Request_URI1: (null)
X-Request_URI2: /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html
Set-Cookie: frontdoor=yes_"httpdocs__my__test.html/dl/my/test.html"; path=/; domain=127.0.0.1; expires=Tue, 19-Oct-2021 13:18:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

So, yeah - finally I can see the expected mod_rewrite string substitution/replacement in headers, even if the rewritten URI is incorrect (i.e. does not correctly map to existing local filesystem data) -- which is what I wanted to achieve.

For fun, this is what comes out of the Apache error (that is, mod_rewrite) log:

```
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.007369 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /subfold/dl/my/test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.007369 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] pass through /subfold/dl/my/test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [setenvif:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_setenvif.c(630): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] Setting REWRGO
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] add path info postfix: C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold -> C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/my/test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] applying pattern 'subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$' to uri 'C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/my/test.html'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] RewriteCond: input='/subfold/dl/my/test.html' pattern='^/subfold/dl/' => matched
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] rewrite 'C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/my/test.html' -> 'httpdocs__my__test.html'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] add per-dir prefix: httpdocs__my__test.html -> /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] add path info postfix: /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html -> /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html/dl/my/test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] strip per-dir prefix: /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html/dl/my/test.html -> httpdocs__my__test.html/dl/my/test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'httpdocs__my__test.html/dl/my/test.html'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] setting env variable 'RSLT' to 'httpdocs__my__test.html/dl/my/test.html'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] setting cookie 'frontdoor=yes_"httpdocs__my__test.html/dl/my/test.html"; path=/; domain=127.0.0.1; expires=Tue, 19-Oct-2021 13:21:55 GMT'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] forcing '/subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] trying to replace context docroot C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs with context prefix
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b22d90/initial] [perdir /subfold/dl/] internal redirect with /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] init rewrite engine with requested uri /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] pass through /subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [setenvif:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_setenvif.c(630): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] Setting REWRGO
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] [perdir /subfold/dl/] add path info postfix: C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold -> C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] [perdir /subfold/dl/] applying pattern 'subfold/dl/(.*)/(.*)$' to uri 'C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] [perdir /subfold/dl/] add path info postfix: C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold -> C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] [perdir /subfold/dl/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] setting env variable 'RSLT' to 'C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold/dl/httpdocs__my__test.html'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] skipping already set cookie 'frontdoor'
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] [perdir /subfold/dl/] forcing 'C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
[Mon Oct 18 15:21:55.008369 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15508:tid 1936] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:12206] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#f88ee0][rid#6b1a020/initial/redir#1] [perdir /subfold/dl/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/bin/Apache24/htdocs/subfold [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Finally, note:

- Now that our RewriteRule does not insist on ^start of string, the cookie value does not contain the starting part of the absolute path as before
- However, we still have the absolute local (`C:/...`) path for RSLT -  and that persist, even if we add [P] (for proxy) or [R=302] (for redirect) flags to the RewriteRule (there will be no change in behavior, since the page regardless returns 404)
- For some reason, `SetEnvIf Cookie` doesn't match the cookie, even if the cookie get written out
- Even if `%{REQUEST_URI}` definitely exists, it does not get output in header via the `"%{REQUEST_URI}e"` syntax - it only gets output via the `"expr=%{REQUEST_URI}"` syntax, which I guess is an [ap_expr](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html)

Comment: Gave my +1 being impressed by the accuracy and extension of the answer you gave yourself. Keep up the good work!